# My UI view messed up after login (ios swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, authentication, uiview

I created a very simple login page, and when they do match, it will go to the home page.
But it's kinda messed up when it gets into the home screen. the pictures as follow :

[image: Login page]
[image: Home Page that messed up]

where if I put initial view in Home screen view, it will worked as expected like this :

[image: Home screen]

here's my simple code to login :

```
@IBAction func LoginTapped(_ sender: Any) {

    let id = idTxtfield.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let password = passwordTxtfield.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)

    if id == "ID" && password == "Password" {
        let HomeScreenVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeScreenVC") as! HomeScreenVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(HomeScreenVC, animated: true)

        // make it as root view
        self.view.window?.rootViewController = HomeScreenVC
        self.view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    else {
        print("wrong password")
    }
}
```

Did I do anything wrong here?
Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What? You are why you are pushing the view controller if you need it in the root view controller?  , And  making it root view controller is  also  wrong, instead of self.view.window try to use app delegate window or scene delegate window

Comment: I don't understand man. I push view controller to move from login to home page. then make the home page as a root cause I do not want the user to login everytime they open the app. they only need to login when user presses logout button. how do I create the delegates window?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your code, the most important one is the fact that you're pushing your home view controller, while also setting it as a root view controller. You shouldn't do both, and that's probably the reason why your UI looked messed up.

If you want to simply push it on the screen, simply use:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(homeViewController, animated: true)
```

But if you want to completely change the root view controller, then you need to access your app window and set the new root view controller (with or without animation). Assuming you have only one window in your app, you could access it like so:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })
```

Also, it's always a good practice to use Lower Camel Case for your property or methods names, and Upper Camel Case for your struct, enum, or class names.

So finally, your `didTapLogin()` method would become:

```
@IBAction func didTapLogin() {
    guard let username = usernameTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, username == "some_username", password == "some_password" else {
        // Wrong password
        return
    }
    guard let mainWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow }) else { return }
    let homeViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(identifier: "HomeScreenVC") as! HomeScreenVC
    mainWindow.rootViewController = homeViewController
    UIView.transition(with: mainWindow, duration: 1.0, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: nil, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what is `keyWindow` in `keyWindow.rootViewController = homeViewController ` ?
why I got error of unresolve identifier `keyWindow` ?

Comment: Sorry it should be mainWindow, I mistyped! :)